# Extjs 4.2 store.sync() creating/updating

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have this store:

**STORE**

```
Ext.define('App.mystore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model:      'App.mymodel',
autoLoad: false,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        read: 'read.php',
        create: 'create.php',
        update: 'update.php'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        totalProperty: 'total',
        successProperty: 'success'
    },
    writer: {
        root: 'records',
        encode: true,
        writeAllFields: false
    }
}
});
```

This store is of a Grid where clicking a button I can add a row,and if I select some previous(inserted yet in database) row I can edit its data.

When all is finished I click a button to sync the store with the database.

This button call a function with this code:

```
onSave:function(){
    var Store=Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mygrid')[0].getStore();

    Store.getProxy().setExtraParam('param1',this.Param1);
    Store.getProxy().setExtraParam('param2',this.Param2);
    Store.getProxy().setExtraParam('param3',this.Param3);

    Store.sync({
        scope:this,
        success : function(response){
            Ext.Msg.show({ 
                title: 'Information', 
                msg: 'All OK',
                icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
            });
        },
        failure:function(response){
            Ext.Msg.show({ 
                title: 'warning',
                msg: 'Error',
                icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
            });
        }
    });
},
```

Can I sync the store in two steps,first new records,then modified records?Because I need to know if both actions where successfully. Because the users can have added new rows and edited some old ones.

Answer (score 0):

The store's "[beforesync](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-beforesync)" event might be useful here. The first arguments is an object with the operation type as key, and list of operations as values. So you might be able to manipulate what kind of operations will be performed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.